# Webpack and .css

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

```
mm2:OptionsAPI ivan$ npm -v
6.13.4
```

When including a `.css` file,

```
import BaseTable, { Column } from 'react-base-table'
import 'react-base-table/styles.css'
```

I get an error like this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-base-table/styles.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .BaseTable {
|   box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #eeeeee;
|   background-color: #ffffff;
 @ ./wwwroot/source/optionsList.jsx 14:0-38
 @ ./wwwroot/source/app.js
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
more webpack.config.js 
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: { 'main': './wwwroot/source/app.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**Am I missing something in the `webpack` for parsing `.css`?**

**EDIT 1**

As per the recommendation in the comments, I modified the `webpack.config.js` file to this:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: { 'main': './wwwroot/source/app.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
              {
                  loader: "style-loader"
              },
              {
                  loader: "css-loader",
                  options: {
                      modules: false,
                      importLoaders: 2,
                      sourceMap: true,
                      minimize: true
                  }
              }
          ]
      },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I get a different error:

```
ERROR in ./wwwroot/source/optionsList.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/Users/ivan/Documents/Projects/OptionsAPI'
 @ ./wwwroot/source/optionsList.jsx 14:0-38
 @ ./wwwroot/source/app.js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! moviesapi@1.0.0 wbp: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the moviesapi@1.0.0 wbp script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ivan/.npm/_logs/2020-01-06T18_31_42_598Z-debug.log
```

**EDIT 2**

After Install the loaders with `npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev` new error:

```
npm run wbp

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"modules":false,"importLoaders":2,"sourceMap":true,"minimize":true}!./node_modules/react-base-table/styles.css
Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals?, esModule? }
    at validate (/Users/ivanfigueredo/Documents/Projects/OptionsAPI/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/Users/ivanfigueredo/Documents/Projects/OptionsAPI/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:34:28)
 @ ./node_modules/react-base-table/styles.css 2:26-87
 @ ./wwwroot/source/optionsList.jsx
 @ ./wwwroot/source/app.js
```

Comment: Remove the `minimize` property and try again.  Like the error said "These properties are valid:" and "minimize" isn't one of them.

Comment: That works thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `rules` and run `npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev`.

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: "style-loader"
        },
        {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                modules: false,
                importLoaders: 2,
                sourceMap: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That does seem to help a little. See EDIT 1 in OP.

Comment: Install the loaders with `npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Try 
import './react-base-table/styles.css' or 
import './styles.css'

If those still fails, try inline styling for debugging